# What are the advantages and disadvantages of two methods of implement a worker/manager separated cluster

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing

There are 2 models to implement a worker/manager separated cluster.

One model is "Manager and worker node separated setup". 
This model consists of two sub cluster domains as worker domain and management domain.  Load will be distributed to these sub-domains according to the defined load balancing algorithm.

The other model is "Dual-mode setup where one node acts as both worker and manager".
This model consists of a single cluster, where a selected node works as both a worker and a manager. This worker node requires two load balancers and configured in read-write mode, while the other worker nodes are set up in read-only mode. The management node also should be a well-known member in the non-management worker nodes so that state replication and cluster messaging works.

I want to know What are the advantages and disadvantages of them and their respective suitable for what kind of application.

Does anyone know about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantages of this model is clearly given in the blog of Afkham Azeez, Director of Architecture at WSO2 on http://blog.afkham.org/2012/08/separation-of-worker-management-nodes.html

Both the models have above mentioned advantages, And in the dual mode the users would still have the separation of worker-manager in the cluster but has the capability of using manager node to serve requests as well which can be important when a user needs to setup a worker-manager cluster with limited resources and wants all the cluster nodes to server requests.

worker-manager clustering architecture is compatible with many WSO2 products like WSO2 Application Server, ESB, Governance Registry , Identity Server and etc. Therefor any application that you host on these servers would be subjected to High availability through this model.

Comment: I have another question.

According to your answer, in the condition of limited resources, we can use dual mode. 

But in this mode, we need one more ELB, it also need consumed resources. Is it right?

Comment: The number of ELB nodes on a deployment setup would hardly change where you can decide at the beginning the needed number of ELB nodes to load balance (including HA for ELB), but the number of worker nodes has to be changed as per the request load (TPS), mostly should be increased, therefor in this model since you can use the management nodes to server requests as well, the necessity to increase worker nodes may not occur frequently. But as mentioned you have to maintain two ELBs for this.

Comment: I see.Thank you for your explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Once of the advantages of configuring them as separate nodes is the ability to keep the management node behind your firewall and only your worker nodes open to the public.

More info here regarding cluster topologies:

https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32346071